# modifying special numbers line by line with sed

Tags: bash, sed

Say I have text in a source file like that:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ...
    if(strcmp(argv[97], "param97") != 0)
        exit(325);

    ...

    if(strcmp(argv[98], "param98") != 0)
        exit(328);
    ...
}
```

Now I want to increment all numbers that are parameters to argv by one and all numbers that are parameters to exit by three. So that the output would look like

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    ...
    if(strcmp(argv[98], "param97") != 0)
        exit(328);

    ...

    if(strcmp(argv[99], "param98") != 0)
        exit(331);
    ...
}
```

I want to do this between a special range inside a textfile, so the command should look like:

```
sed -n 1224,1482p file | sed <...>
```

Can someone give me a hint how the second sed command should look like?

**Edit**:

I figured out how I can solve this using sed:

```
sed -n 1224,1482p file | sed 's/\(.*\)\(argv\)\[\([0-9]\+\)\]\(.*\)/echo "\1\2"\[$(echo "\3+1"\|bc)\]"\4"/ge; s/\(.*\)\(exit\)(\([0-9]\+\))\(.*\)/echo "\1\2("$(echo "\3+3"\|bc)")\4"/ge'
```

I used the e flag for allowing me to pipe into the shell command bc to increment the said numbers.

Comment: Are you required to use SED, or you can use Perl, for example?

Comment: perl is fine too. I would be just curious how that would be done with sed

Comment: @FloHe, yeah, it is possible with `sed` to do arithmetic.. have a look https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36949/addition-with-sed and decide ;)

Comment: try `perl -pe 'if(1224..1482){ s/argv\[\K\d+(?=])/$&+1/e; s/exit\(\K\d+(?=\))/$&+3/e }' file`

Comment: Can't you just write the entire thing as a for loop from 1 to N?  Or your real code is more complex than what you have here?

Comment: Yes, it actually is. There isn't a correlation between argv[<nmbr>]  and "param". This means I don't have lines like
   if(strcmp(argv[99], "param98") != 0)
but rather
if(strcmp(argv[99], "qwert") != 0)

Comment: @FloHe - you should make than an answer.